# 小さいサイズのメモリ環境（例RAM 10KB)でgzip圧縮できるライブラリ

Tags: gzip

小さいサイズのメモリ環境（例RAM 10KB)でgzip圧縮できるライブラリと
してどのようなものがあるか知りたいです。

目的：装置からサーバへのデータ送信時にデータサイズを小さくしたい。
　　　　　（送信データサイズは圧縮前20kB程度）
　CPU:ARM Cortex-M4
　この処理で使えるRAMサイズ：15KB程度
　その他：解凍処理は未実装でOK

Answer (score 6):

[zlib - Technical Details - Memory Footprint](https://zlib.net/zlib_tech.html)によると

> The memory requirements for compression depend on two parameters, **windowBits** and **memLevel**:
>
> ```
> deflate memory usage (bytes) = (1 << (windowBits+2)) + (1 << (memLevel+9))
> ```

とのことですので、これを踏まえて`windowBits`（最低値8）と`memLevel`（最低値1）を適切に指定すればいいと思います。

Comment: 具体的な情報ありがとうございます。

Comment: 参考にさせていただきます。助かりました。